# How to configure keycloak to store its data in database encrypted?

Tags: keycloak

I need to encrypt sensitive data stored in Keycloak database (ie. firstname, lastname). How to configure keycloak to store them encrypted in database?

I'm using Keycloak 7.0.0 and PostgreSql 10.6 as its database.

Comment: It doesn't look like Keycloak has such a possibility. Even if you'll modify Keycloak's source code to encrypt/decrypt data, lets say username, then some things will be broken (Sorting/Ordering won't work as it is done in SQL query). Other option - you can try to use Postgres possibilities to encrypt data https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/encryption-options.html